# How to create view with NOT NULL constraints?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, view, notnull

I made some view based on two tables. In the table I have NOT NULL in two columns, but my view doesn't have any NOT NULL, how can I make this view with the same properties as in tables? In that situation a want to have my id and line_id NOT NULL as in the table under the view.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.shell_leak_measurements_view
AS SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY slm.id) AS id,
    slm.line_id,
    l.gis_ext_id,
    slm.date,
    slm.duration,
    slm.result,
    slm.value,
    slm.comments 
   FROM shell_leak_measurements slm
     JOIN lines l ON l.id = slm.line_id;

CREATE TABLE public.shell_leak_measurements (
id int4 NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
line_id int4 NOT NULL,
date date NULL,
duration int4 NULL,
result int4 NULL,
value float8 NULL,
comments varchar(1000) NULL,
CONSTRAINT shell_leak_measurements_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT shell_leak_measurement_line_fk FOREIGN KEY (line_id) REFERENCES public.lines(id)
```

);

Comment: Views do't have constraints. They are just query definitions that are combined into queries.

Comment: The SELECT decides null/not null.